# Cannot create gallery page using Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to create a gallery landing page (see attached screenshots for the layout that I am trying to set up). I tried to start off with creating a views based image gallery using the tutorial at https://www.drupal.org/node/1497058 .
However the images are not being displayed after I create the view.  What am I doing wrong? How can I create the layout that is shown on the screenshots?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer you looking for it is not quite simple. I will get you trough main things you should do.

1. Make content type gallery with fields: Gallery title, Gallery image
   (field type: image), Gallery category (field type: term reference),
   Gallery header (field type: text)
2. Make image style for thumbnails with desired size
3. Install some js solution for image opening (colorbox, juicebox, etc)
4. In gallery content type display select on format image installed js and set up the rest (there you select your priview image style, js style, captions...)
5. Create gallery view from gallery content type
6. Add fields in that view (gallery image, gallery category, gallery header, date, title)
7. Create gallery category view where your field will be term (gallery category)
8. Include gallery category view  in your gallery view with filter taxonomy term (because you want to preview images based on category)
9. Format pager for gallery view
10. Format your view look (this is a whole another topic because you
     can do that on so many ways)

I see on your layout you want to set pager on every category but in Drupal one view have just one pager. So you must either hard code core basic view pagination or you can make different view on every category and then include them all in one main view. My suggestion is not to have pager on every category. Reduce your requests and with instruction above you can make very nice gallery using Drupal views.

P.S. This question is in range with :"*How to make a app from this screenshot in X technology*" but i had some time and i wanted to help. Good luck with your work.